# openbsd installer doesn't recognize disks?

Tags: system-installation, openbsd

**Background:**

I'm absolutely new to OpenBSD and trying to install OpenBSD 6.5 into Dell G3 3779.

At first, the OpenBSD's UEFI bootloader showed that it detected 3 disks, including the bootable USB flash drive.

```
boot > machine diskinfo
Disk  BlkSiz IoAlign Size  Flags Checksum
hd0   512    0       28GB  0x4   ....      Removable
hd1   512    1       931GB 0x0   ....
hd2   512    1       119GB 0x0   ....
```

According to the PC spec, it has 128GB SSD and 1TB HDD. So this looked alright.

I continued boot and install..

```
> boot
...
sd0 as scsibus0 targ 1 lun 0: <ELECOM, MF-HTU3, PMAP> SCSI4 0/direct removable serial.056e....
sd0: 29574MB, 512 bytes/sector, 60567552 sectors
...
Welcome to the OpenBSD/amd64 6.5 installation program.
(I)nstall, (U)pgrade, (A)utoinstall or (S)hell?  I
...
...
```

However, at disk settings step, I stopped and wondered that the installer was going to install the OS into the USB drive, not disks in the PC.

```
Available disks are: sd0.
Which disk is the root disk? ('?' for details) [sd0] (press enter key)
Disk:  sd0  geometry: 3770/255/63 [60567552 Sectors]
Offset:  0  Signegure: 0xAA55
#: id  C  H  S -  C  H  S
0: EF  0  1  2 -  0 16 16 [    64:    960 ] EFI Sys
1: 00  0  0  0 -  0  0  0 [     0:      0 ] unused
2: 00  0  0  0 -  0  0  0 [     0:      0 ] unused
3: A6  0 16 17 - 57 92 35 [  1024: 920512 ] OpenBSD
```

It seemed to show only 1 disk for disk setting, and the `sd0` seemed being recoginized as the USB device.

**Question:**

Was this right installer's behavior?
Or is it right guess that the installer couldn't detect the hard disks although the bootloader could?

P.S English is not my native language; please excuse typing, grammar or/and word selecting errors.

**UPDATE1:** 'not configured' lines in dmesg

```
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
acpiec at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpicpu at acpi0 not configured
acpitz at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0A08" at acpi0 not configured
"INT3403" at acpi0 not configured
"INT3403" at acpi0 not configured
"INT3403" at acpi0 not configured
"INT3450" at acpi0 not configured
"DELL0870" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"INT33A1" at acpi0 not configured
"MSFT0101" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0D" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0C" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0E" at acpi0 not configured
"ACPI0003" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0A" at acpi0 not configured
"INT3305" at acpi0 not configured
"INT3400" at acpi0 not configured
vendor "NVIDIA", unknown product 0x1c8c (class display subclass 30, rev 0xa1) at pci1 dev 0 function 0 not configured
"Intel UHD Graphics 630" rev 0x00 at pci0 dev 2 function 0 not configured
"Intel Core 6G Thermal" rev 0x07 at pci0 dev 4 function 0 not configured
"Intel Core GMM" rev 0x00 at pci0 dev 8 function 0 not configured
vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa36f (class memory subclass RAM, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 20 function 2 not configured
"Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 9560" rev 0x10 at pci0 dev 20 function 3 not configured
vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa368 (class serial bus unknown subclass 0x00, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 21 function 0 not configured
vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa369 (class serial bus unknown subclass 0x00, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 21 function 1 not configured
vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa360 (class communications subclass miscellaneous, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 22 function 0 not configured
vendor "Intel", uknown product 0xa30d (class bridge subclass ISA, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 31 function 0 not configured
vendor "Intel", uknown product 0xa348 (class multimedia subclass hdaudio, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 31 function 3 not configured
vendor "Intel", uknown product 0xa323 (class serial bus subclass SMBus, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 31 function 4 not configured
vendor "Intel", uknown product 0xa324 (class serial bus subclass 0x00, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 31 function 5 not configured
"CNFFH370344001E31F2 Integrated_Webcam_HD" rev 2.00/64.26 addr 2 at uhub0 port 5 not configured
"Generic USB2.0-CAW" rev 2.00/39.60 addr 3 at uhub0 port 6 not configured
"HTMicroelectronics Goodix Fingerprint Device" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 4 at uhub0 port 9 not configured
"vendor 0x0087 product 0x0aaa" rev 2.00/0.02 addr 5 port 14 not configured
```

**UPDATE2:** All lines in dmesg

```
OpenBSD 6.5 (RAMDISK_CD) #3: Sat Apr 13 14:55:38 MDT 2019
    decreadt@amd64.openbsd.org:/usr/src/sys/arc/amd64/compile/RAMDISK_CD
real mem = 17016164252 (16227MB)
avail mem = 16496480256 (15732MB)
mainbus0 at root
bios0 at mainbus0: SMBIOS rev. 3.1 @ 0xe000 (128 entries)
bios0: vendor  Dell Inc. version “1.4.0” date 09/05/2018
bios0: Dell Inc. G3 3779
acpi0 at bios0: rev 2
acpi0: tables DSDT FACP APIC FPDT FIDT MCFG SSDT SSDT BOOT HPET SSDT UEFI LPIT SSDT SSDT DBGP DBG2 SSDT SSDT MSDM SLIC SSDT SSDT DMAR BGRT UEFI TPM2 SSDT
acpimadt0 at acpi0 addr 0xfee00000: PC-AT compat
cpu0 at mainbus0: apid 0 (boot processor)
cpu0: Intel(R)Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz, 3893.13 MHz, 06-9e-0a
cpu0: FPU,VME,DE,PSE,TSC,MSR,PAE,MCE,CX8,APIC,SEP,MTRR,PGE,MCA,CMOV,PAT, PSE36,CFLUSH,DS,ACPI,MMX,FXSR,SSE,SSE2,SS,HTT,TM,PBE,SSE3,PCLMUL,DTES46, MWAIT,DS-CPL,VMX,EST,TM2,SSSE3,SDBG,FMA3,CX16,xTPR,PDCM,PCID,SSE4.1, SSE4.2,x2APIC,MOVBE,POPCNT,DEADLINE,AES,XSAVE,AVX,F16C,RDRAND,NXE, PAGE16B,ADTSCP,LONG,LAHF,ABM,3DNOWP,PERF,ITSC,FSGSBASE,SGX,BMI1,AVX2, SMEP,BMI2,EAMS,INVPCID,MPX,RDSEED,ADX,SMAP,CLFLUSHOPT,PT,IBAS,IBPB, STIBP,L1DF,SSBD,SENSOR,AAAT,XSAVEOPT,XSAVEC,XGETBV1,XSAVES,MELTDOWN
cpu0: 256KB 64b/line 8-way L21 cache
cpu0: apic clock running at 24MHz
cpu0: mwait min=64, max=64, C-substates=0.2.1.2.4.1.1.1, IBE
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
cpu at mainbus0: not configured
ioapic0 at mainbus0: apid 2 pa 0xfec00000, version 20, 120 pins
acpiprt0 at acpi0: bus 0 (PCI0)
acpiprt1 at acpi0: bus 1 (PEG0)
acpiprt2 at acpi0: bus -1 (PEG1)
acpiprt3 at acpi0: bus -1 (PEG2)
acpiprt4 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP01)
acpiprt5 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP02)
acpiprt6 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP03)
acpiprt7 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP04)
acpiprt8 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP05)
acpiprt9 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP06)
acpiprt10 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP07)
acpiprt11 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP08)
acpiprt12 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP09)
acpiprt13 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP10)
acpiprt14 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP11)
acpiprt15 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP12)
acpiprt16 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP13)
acpiprt17 at acpi0: bus 59 (AP14)
acpiprt18 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP16)
acpiprt19 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP17)
acpiprt20 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP18)
acpiprt21 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP19)
acpiprt22 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP20)
acpiprt23 at acpi0: bus 2 (AP21)
acpiprt24 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP22)
acpiprt25 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP23)
acpiprt26 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP24)
acpiprt27 at acpi0: bus -1 (AP15)
acpiec0 at acpi0
acpiec at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
acpicpu at acpi0 not configured
acpitz at acpi0 not configured
acpipwrres at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0A08" at acpi0 not configured
acpicmos0 at acpi0
"INT3403" at acpi0 not configured
"INT3403" at acpi0 not configured
"INT3403" at acpi0 not configured
"INT3450" at acpi0 not configured
"DELL0870" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"INT33A1" at acpi0 not configured
"MSFT0101" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C14" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0D" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0C" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0E" at acpi0 not configured
"ACPI0003" at acpi0 not configured
"PNP0C0A" at acpi0 not configured
"INT3305" at acpi0 not configured
"INT3400" at acpi0 not configured
pci0 at mainbus0 bus0
0:31:5: mem address conflict 0xfe010000/0x1000
pchb0 at pci0 dev 0 function 0 "Intel Core 8G Host" rev 0x07
ppb0 at cpi0 dev 1 function 0 "Intel Core 6G PCIE" rev 0x07: msi
pci1 at ppb0 bus 1
vendor "NVIDIA", unknown product 0x1c8c (class display subclass 30, rev 0xa1) at pci1 dev 0 function 0 not configured
"Intel UHD Graphics 630" rev 0x00 at pci0 dev 2 function 0 not configured
"Intel Core 6G Thermal" rev 0x07 at pci0 dev 4 function 0 not configured
"Intel Core GMM" rev 0x00 at pci0 dev 8 function 0 not configured
vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa379 (class DASP subclass miscellaneous, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 18
xhci0 at pci0 dev 20 function 0 vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa36d rev 0x10: msi, xHCI 1.10
usb0 at xhci0: USB revision 3.0
uhub0 at usb0 configuration 1 interface 0 "Intel xHCI root hub" rev 3.00/1.00 addr 1
vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa36f (class memory subclass RAM, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 20 function 2 not configured
"Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 9560" rev 0x10 at pci0 dev 20 function 3 not configured
vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa368 (class serial bus unknown subclass 0x00, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 21 function 0 not configured
vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa369 (class serial bus unknown subclass 0x00, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 21 function 1 not configured
vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa360 (class communications subclass miscellaneous, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 22 function 0 not configured
pciide0 at pci0 dev 23 function 0 "Intel 82801HBM RAID" rev 0x10: DMA, channel 0 wired to native-PCI, channel 1 wired to native-PCI
pciide0: using apic 2 int 16 for native-PCI interrupt
ppb1 at pci0 dev 27 function 0 vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa32c rev 0xf0: msi
pci2 at ppb1 bus 2
ppb2 at pci0 dev 29 function 0 vendor "Intel", unknown product 0xa335 rev 0xf0: msi
pci3 at ppb2 bus 59
re0 at pci3 dev 0 function 0 "Realtek 8168" rev 0x15: RTL8168H/8111H (0x5400), msi, address 3c:2c:30:ac:c8:59
rgephy0 at re0 phy 7: RTL8251 PHY, rev. 0
vendor "Intel", uknown product 0xa30d (class bridge subclass ISA, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 31 function 0 not configured
vendor "Intel", uknown product 0xa348 (class multimedia subclass hdaudio, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 31 function 3 not configured
vendor "Intel", uknown product 0xa323 (class serial bus subclass SMBus, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 31 function 4 not configured
vendor "Intel", uknown product 0xa324 (class serial bus subclass 0x00, rev 0x10) at pci0 dev 31 function 5 not configured
isa0 at mainbus0
pckbc0 at isa0 port 0x60/5 irq 1 irq 12
pckbd0 at pckbc0 (kbd slot)
wskbd0 at pckbd0: console keyboard
efifb0 at mainbus0: 1920x1080, 32bpp
wsdisplay0 at efifb0 mux 1: console (std, vt100 emulation), using wskbd0
"CNFFH370344001E31F2 Integrated_Webcam_HD" rev 2.00/64.26 addr 2 at uhub0 port 5 not configured
"Generic USB2.0-CAW" rev 2.00/39.60 addr 3 at uhub0 port 6 not configured
"HTMicroelectronics Goodix Fingerprint Device" rev 2.00/1.00 addr 4 at uhub0 port 9 not configured
"vendor 0x0087 product 0x0aaa" rev 2.00/0.02 addr 5 port 14 not configured
umass0 at uhub0 port 19 configuration 1 interface 0 "ELECOM MF-HTU3" rev 3.10/1.10 addr 6
umass0: using SCSI over Bulk-Only
scsibus0 at umass0: 2 targets, initiator 0
sd0 at scsibus0 targ 1 lun 0: <ELECOM, MF-HTU3, PMAP> SCSI4 0/direct removable serial.056e6016774D0C907014
sd0: 29574MB, 512 bytes/sector, 60567552 sectors
softraid0 at root
scsibus1 at softraid0: 256 targets
root on rd0a swap on rd0b dump on rd0b
```

Comment: It'd be helpful to know what's the SATA (?) controller on your machine.  Can you update your question with it?  It'll probably be listed on your `dmesg` as "not configured".

Comment: A RAID controller is detected: `pciide0 at pci0 dev 23 function 0 "Intel 82801HBM RAID"`. In all likelihood your SATA controller is configured in "RAID mode". In all likelihood you can switch it back to "SATA mode" on the BIOS. If you really want/need RAID you can always let OpenBSD handle it (see `man softraid` and `man bioctl`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Ze Loff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/77520/z%c3%a9-loff) told in a comment, it was the SATA controller setting in Bios. The default was using RAID. I changed it to using AHCI.
After that, the kernel detected all drives as the bootloader.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. UEFI presents the disk correctly to the bootloader, but the kernel (more specifically the kernel that comes with the installer) doesn't recognize the HDD controller, so the installer doesn't "see" those disks.  The USB controller is recognized, though, so the only available disk for the installer is the installed media itself.

Check the `dmesg` for "not configured" lines, you'll probably find your controller there.  Also, post a *full* `dmesg` on `misc@openbsd.org`, so that the developers can find you that particular board isn't working and try to come up with a solution.  If anyone else has came across the same issue and found a workaround they'll be able to help you out.

Comment: I added dmesg information. but it's beyond my knowledge. Can you suggest if there are any consice ways to identify the right HDD controller?