# OpenBSD installation script does not recognise SATA-connected drives

Tags: system-installation, raid, openbsd, ssd, bios

My question is one that has been posted here before but merits a new thread since the solution given did not work for me. During the OpenBSD installation, only one device is recognized as a candidate for holding the root partition, that being `sd0`, the USB stick that holds the installation image.

Some relevant pictures of my screen showing configuration and issues: https://imgur.com/a/rR8Nn3h

In [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565313/openbsd-unix-usb-install-bios-recognizes-hard-drive-but-openbsd-install-does-n) as well as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526924/openbsd-installer-doesnt-recognize-disks), the same issue was presented, and it turned out that their hardware was configured with RAID rather than SATA. So I looked in my BIOS settings, and both of the internal drives are set to SATA (last two pictures in imgur album). It even explicitly says "Non-RAID".

My `dmesg` output in full is included as the first few pictures of the imgur album (sorry, no text; I'm not sure how to do that with the very limited install shell).

Disclaimer: I am using an the version of `bootx64.efi` that was bundled with 6.6 as a workaround for [this issue](https://www.mail-archive.com/misc@openbsd.org/msg174083.html). I am not sure how that would break anything, but I should mention it regardless.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  There are not discussion threads here.  There are questions, answers, and comments upon them.  Also note that to people including me your screenshot is invisible.  At minimum, at least put the image directly in the question.  But note https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/5132 .  If you can write the output of `dmesg` to a file, that is best to do.

Comment: I apologize. I did not intend to create a discussion. And I have tried to write dmesg to the file, but this is a filesystem running in ram. I have tried to mount devices but they are "not configured" at best and nonexistent at worst. The `sd0` device is one of the latter, possibly due to the reason I posted this question. I dislike posting images as much as anyone, but it seems I have no other option. I will try to add the images to the post though. Didn't know I could do that or that's what I would have done.